# What's the difference of CTFT $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t) e^{-j \Omega t} dt$ and CTFT of $e^{j \Omega_0 t}$?

Tags: fourier-transform

What's the difference of CTFT $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t) e^{-j \Omega t} dt$ and CTFT of $e^{j \Omega_0 t}$?

Because if one sets $f(t)= e^{j \Omega_0 t}$, then shouldn't this be calculated by:

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t) e^{-j \Omega t} dt \text{ ?}$

But this gives

$= 2 \pi \delta( \omega - (\Omega_0 - \Omega))$

which is different from $2 \pi \delta(\omega-\Omega_0)=F(\omega)$.

So which one is it?

Or maybe one has to reparametrize so that $\omega_F =\omega+\Omega$?

Comment: If CTFT = Continuous Time Fourier Transform, you can drop the "CT" :  a majority of Fourier transform users do this one...

Comment: @JeanMarie It's the Continuous-Time Fourier Transform.

Comment: As I understand your question, you are asking what is the effect of a frequency shift (you should abandon the reference to a general $f(t)$) on a Fourier transform. My answer would be : look at your Fourier formulas...

Comment: @JeanMarie You mean there's some kind of invariance property?

Comment: Where does $\omega$ enter into $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t) e^{-j \Omega t} dt$?

Comment: @πr8 I believe it's common to denote the signal $f(t)$ and its Fourier transform $F(\omega)$. So it's a reparametrization of $t$.

Comment: @πr8 Actually this chart https://www.ethz.ch/content/dam/ethz/special-interest/baug/ibk/structural-mechanics-dam/education/identmeth/fourier.pdf seems to clear the confusion. $f(t)$ is not used to refer to what's in side the integral, but to the entire Inverse Fourier transform expression.